# Creating Win32 resource files on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, winapi, encryption, openssl, stub

I'm having a super frustrating issue.

Basically, I want to write C code that encrypts a binary file, and then creates a Win32 resource file that can be packaged into a resulting executable file.

I found the best way to do this was to use a C program to generate an `encrypted.dat` file with the encrypted executable code, then create a resource script that packages this code into an executable.

My main issue here is that I'm working on a Mac, and the resource compiler `RC` that is included in the Windows SDK is not available on OSX.

Can anyone explain how I can accomplish this project without completely switching to Windows? The main issue is that I can't generate and link the resource file that I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have a program named "windres" (maybe x86_64-w32-ming32-windres or some other platform, that is the GCC equivalent of rc.exe